# Running .NET project Jasmine tests in Azure pipeline build server

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, jasmine, resharper, build-server

There are some Jasmine unit tests inside the .NET Framework project, we could able to run the unit tests in Visual Studio-19 via ReSharper. We already have a Build server in Azure pipeline which is configured to Build and run the .NET Framework Unit Tests.

Is there any way to configure the Jasmine tests to run in the Azure DevOps pipeline with the same build server we already have.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You should install jasmine tooling on your build server depending on its nature virtual server/container. Build agents are machines that have a devops agent installed. You can configure as you want your private build agent and instruct it to perform any action using your pipeline

Comment: @GeralexGR Sounds great. Is there procedures to configure Jasmine tests?, it would be helpful if you refer any website to proceed further.

Comment: As I can see from the official page, you could install it through node. https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html

Comment: @GeralexGR Thanks for this, but i need a procedures/steps to configure in Azure Pipeline?.

Comment: You should install jasmine unit tests on your custom build agent. You will be able then to execute the tests commands on your pipeline. Its like installing a software on your computer and then using it through cmd